# Xcode build fails when we select profile and certificate in titanium

Tags: titanium

I am able to build the code using titanium command. when we build the code using xocode5 by selecting profile and certificate from build settings then only below error comes.

**[ERROR] : ?? ?Invalid "--developer-name" value "iPhone Distribution: Global Services Limited"
[ERROR] : ?? ?Invalid "--pp-uuid" value "FD4487D7-99D0-42F5-B9E2-471E17F964E4"
For help, run: titanium help build
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code** **1**

CLI 3.2.0

Node.ACS 1.0.11

Alloy 1.3.0

NOTE: If i don't select any profile and certificate then above error will not come.
In my case i have the change the profile and certificate.

Regards,

Venkatesh

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/161067/trying-to-archive-for-ad-hoc-but-gets-error-i-xcode---developer-name----pp-uuid

however, for me its not clear as well what needs to be matched (profile name and app common name ?) whats that "exactly" ? its not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem and this seemed to work:

First go to your Xcode project and click the folder at the top left of the left pane, then click on your project. That will open up your settings on the right.

Click on the build settings tab and scroll down to code signing and make sure you have the correct code signing and provisioning profile selected.

Click on capabilities and turn them all off. It will prompt you for a profile when turning them on or off and I had a different profile selected for store than for the build process. I'm not sure why it was enabled in the first place, as I am not using that feature, but changing the profile here seemed to get me past the build error you are having.

Answer (score 0):

We have identified the issue and have created a/another ticket to fix it: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17034.

I’ll be working on fixing it real soon and the fix is scheduled to be available in Titanium SDK 3.3.0 whenever that ships. You’ll be able to preview the fix in an upcoming RC build.

You may have some luck if you open the Xcode project, then go to the Build Phases and find the “Pre-Compile” script. Edit the call to “ti build” and add:

`--developer-name "Your developer name" --pp-uuid "your pp uuid"`

More information [here](https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/161067/trying-to-archive-for-ad-hoc-but-gets-error-i-xcode---developer-name----pp-uuid)